# check if NHibernate entity is contained in multiple entities

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to ensure that an entity is contained in at most one single entity.
Is it possible to check this from the mapping files?  In SQL land, I want to ensure
that if a table has a foreign key, that there are no repeated entries in the foreign key column.

Thanks!

Jorge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the FK unique:

```
<many-to-one unique="true" />
```

Or, from the collection side:

```
<key>
  <column unique="true"/>
</key>
```

(I omitted all attributes non related to the problem)

Comment: Thanks, Diego. But, I am a little confused. My understanding is that a "many-to-one" relation occurs when one object can be used by many other objects. Doesn't "unique=true" contradict this relationship?

Comment: a many-to-one relationship with a unique constraint is effectively a one-to-one. Don't read too much into the names.

Comment: Thanks so much, Diego. The reason I ask this question is because I am trying to build a smarter second level cache for my app. Default implementation evicts query from cache if a table referenced by query has been updated. But, I figure that if I update an entity that is contained by at most one other entity, then this other entity should already be in the entity cache, and so I could re-run the query in memory on the entities in the entity cache, and not have to hit the database again to update the query. Does this sound feasible? My application is the only one updating the DB.

Comment: There are too many missing details to know if it would be feasible... Personally, I'd rather use the existing NH query/entity caches, with whatever optimizations you want (there are enough extension points).

Comment: Thanks, Diego. I am taking an evolutionary approach; take existing caches and add a few new features. Like updating a query in the cache instead of evicting it. And ignoring the timestamp cache. If this is possible through extension points, I would do it this way.